# Java CSV Formatting Issues

Tags: java, csv, stringbuilder

I am reading a `HashMap` and creating a CSV file.
The below code accepts a `HashMap` and produce a CSV file. However the formatting is a problem. For a `HashMap`,

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hmap.put("Feature1", 1);
hmap.put("Feature2", 2);
```

It produces

```
Feature2,Feature2,
2,1,Feature1,Feature1,
2,1,
```

Expected Output (*without comma at the end of each line*):

```
Feature2,Feature1
2,1
```

Which is  a wrong formatting

This is the code I use. How to fix it ?

```
public String appendCSV(Map featureset) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder csvReport = new StringBuilder(); 

    Map<String, Integer> map =featureset;
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

    String[] lsitofkeys = {};

    for(String elements:keys){
        for(int i =0 ; i< keys.size(); i++){
             csvReport.append(elements+",");
        }
        csvReport.append("\n");
        for(String key: keys){
            csvReport.append(map.get(key).toString()+",");
        }
    }

  return csvReport.toString();
}
```

Comment: you need to check when you are on the last element. if you are, then you will not append the comma when appending to the csvReport

Comment: You would then have to check every item in the loop. Better remove last character if there are any items. Then you only do it once.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz How to do it ?

Comment: If any values might need to be escaped, consider using a mature CSV library instead of rolling your own CSV writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you have issues with your loop

you need two separate loops (no inner loops);

Also to get rid of that comma at the end, you can use a simple check using a `isFirst` variable like below :)

```
public String appendCSV(Map featureset) throws IOException{
  StringBuilder csvReport = new StringBuilder(); 

  Map<String, Integer> map =featureset;
  Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

  String[] lsitofkeys = {};
  boolean isFirst=true;
  for(String elements : keys){
     if(!isFirst){
       csvReport.append(",");
     }
     csvReport.append(elements);
     isFirst=false;
  }

  csvReport.append("\n");

  isFirst=true;
  for(String elements : keys){
     if(!isFirst){
       csvReport.append(",");
     }
   csvReport.append(map.get(elements));
   isFirst=false;
  }

  return csvReport.toString();
}
```

Comment: Need to convert csReport.toString();

Comment: @Kumaresp yeah sorry mate, just a typo

Comment: If you use a while or for loop instead of foreach, you can avoid the need for isFirst.

Comment: @rob I can't think of a way that using while loop will help to remove  `isFirst` to prevent comma at the end, could you show me how please? ty

Comment: Use an Iterator explicitly, check Iterator.hasNext() and call Iterator.next() before the loop to get the first element, then loop on Iterator.hasNext(). Also, you can use Map.entrySet() to avoid a Map.get() on every iteration.

Comment: @rob I see few complications with iterator, (espeicalliy calling next() without checking hasnext() ) . but yeah in terms of efficiency it'll be better that way. but code will be more complicated. also its better not to call  entrySet() in this scenraio

Comment: @nafas not sure I understand what you mean about the not checking hasNext() or the code being more complicated; if anything, this is a situation in which a `foreach` loop adds complexity over a `for` or `while` loop. Can you clarify why using entrySet would be detrimental here? It would have better performance than performing Map.get() on every key, especially if `featureset` is a TreeMap. Also, I may be missing something but it looks like you can delete `lsitofkeys`, as it is not even used in the OP's code.

Comment: @rob mate, I meant no disrespect, let's just agree how code looks is very opinion based. but regarding this question, it needs to have the key on the first line and the value on the second line, this is why having entry set won't make much of difference, as it still need to loop it twice. once reading the key and once reading the value.

Comment: @nafas no offense taken and apologies if it seemed that way. :) My point regarding entrySet was more along the lines of being able to just print instead of having to do a lookup on every key before being able to print the value. But maybe this is a case of premature optimization. (After more thought, it's also conceivable some implementation of Iterable.iterator() may not give the same sort order 2 times in a row, which would potentially break both our solutions.) That said, it _is_ possible to technically code a single loop; it is just more memory-intensive.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 has `String.join()`:

Having collected the keys and values into lists:

```
 csvReport.append(String.join(",", keys));
 csvReport.append(String.join(",", values));
```

The Streams API has `Collectors.joining()` which helps even more:

```
 List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
 csvReport.append(entries.stream()
     .map(e -> e.getKey())
     .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
 csvReport.append("\n");
      csvReport.append(entries.stream()
     .map(e -> e.getValue())
     .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
 csvReport.append("\n");
```

Both of these ultimately use `StringJoiner`. If you have an academic interest in how to build a joined string without a delimiter at the end, it's worth looking at [the code for `StringJoiner`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/StringJoiner.java) for an elegant example.

---

**However** - There are subtleties to writing CSV and it's a good idea to use a library unless there are reasons (legal, academic) not to. Apache Commons CSV is one.

Comment: I think you can work that out for yourself. You can do it!

Comment: @slim I like the code mate,  I seriously need to start migrating to java 8.

Comment: public String streamCSV(Map featureset) {
  Map<String, Integer> map =featureset;
  List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
  csvReport.append(entries.stream()
      .map(e -> e.getKey())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
  csvReport.append("\n");
       csvReport.append(entries.stream()
      .map(e -> e.getValue())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
  csvReport.append("\n");
}

Answer (score 3):

Just remote the last character of your string if it is longer than 1 character. Here is how to do it: `str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);`

Comment: Can you explain it ? How integrate it with my code ? I don't  have  str variable anywhere?

Comment: Delete the last char from the StringBuilder instead of creating an extra String object.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a separate StringBuilder for the keys and another one for the values. Then as you go through your keys you add them to your key StringBuilder and then take the map given and grab the value associated with that key and add it to your value StringBuilder.

Lastly you just keep track of how many keys you have seen so far. If the number of keys seen is not equal to the size of the map then you append a comma. But if you are on the last element according to the numOfKeys counter, then you append nothing to the end of the StringBuilders.

```
    StringBuilder csvKeyReport = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder csvValueReport = new StringBuilder();

    Map<String, Integer> map = hmap;
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();


    int numOfKeys = 0;

    for(String key : keys)
    {
        numOfKeys++;
        String comma = numOfKeys == map.size() ? "" : ",";
        csvKeyReport.append(key + comma);
        csvValueReport.append(map.get(key) + comma);
    }

    csvKeyReport.append("\n");
    csvKeyReport.append(csvValueReport.toString() + "\n");

    System.out.print(csvKeyReport.toString());
```

Output

```
Feature2,Feature1
2,1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is doing something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapToCSV {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      hmap.put("Feature1", 1);
      hmap.put("Feature2", 2);

      try {
          System.out.println(appendCSV(hmap));
      } catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


   public static String appendCSV(HashMap<String,Integer> featureset) throws IOException{

      StringBuilder csvReport = new StringBuilder(); 
      // loop through the keySet and append the keys
      for(String key: featureset.keySet()){
           csvReport.append(key+",");
      }
      // to remove the comma at the end 
      csvReport.replace(csvReport.length()-1, csvReport.length(), "");
      csvReport.append("\n"); // append new line

      // then loop through the keySet and append the values
      for(String key: featureset.keySet()){
          csvReport.append(featureset.get(key)+",");
      }
      csvReport.replace(csvReport.length()-1, csvReport.length(), "");
      return csvReport.toString();
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
Feature2,Feature1
2,1
```

Comment: Your code produce  wrong format. You can see comma at the end

Comment: @Kumaresp Is it just about removing the comma, that's quite easy, check it now!

Answer (score 1):

You should to create a new stringbuilder into the cycle:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class NewClass {

    public NewClass() throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        hmap.put("Feature1", 1);
        hmap.put("Feature2", 2);
        System.out.print(appendCSV(hmap));
    }

    public String appendCSV(Map featureset) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder csvReport = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder csvReportVal = new StringBuilder();

        Set<String> keys = featureset.keySet();

        for (String elements : keys) {
            csvReport.append(elements + ",");
            csvReportVal.append(featureset.get(elements).toString() + ",");
        }

        // Excluding the latest ","
        csvReport.setLength(csvReport.length() - 1);
        csvReportVal.setLength(csvReportVal.length() - 1);

        csvReport.append("\n" + csvReportVal.toString());
        return csvReport.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new NewClass();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Feature2,Feature1
2,1
```

Comment: Your code produce  wrong format. You can see comma at the end

Comment: Although this technically looks like it produces the desired result, you could improve the readability and efficiency significantly.